# Unable to insert data from text area field - mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically the first form will take data if any edits, and click on save will redirect to above php code.

But I am not getting the edits saved during the form and I am getting error.  Kindly let me know how to fix this!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Google Analytics Code</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="ganalytics" class="form-control" name="ganalytics"><?php echo $ganalytics;?>"</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-10">Facebook Pixel Code</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="fbpixel" class="form-control" name="fbpixel"><?php echo $fbpixel;?>"</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $fbpixel= $_POST['fbpixel'];
    $ganalytics= $_POST['ganalytics'];
    echo $fbpixel;
    echo $ganalytics;
}
```

Comment: `and i am getting error` - Can you expand on this?

Comment: @Lewis : Page isn't working error on chrome

Comment: Is your PHP code _before_ or _after_ the html?

Comment: @Lewis : its before html code, problem is happening only when i have this text area fields, if i comment the echo line  this its working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You have typo an `"` is floating on your code 
change

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="fbpixel" class="form-control" name="fbpixel"><?php echo $fbpixel;?>"</textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="fbpixel" class="form-control" name="fbpixel"><?php echo $fbpixel;?></textarea>
```

and this

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="ganalytics" class="form-control" name="ganalytics"><?php echo $ganalytics;?>"</textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="ganalytics" class="form-control" name="ganalytics"><?php echo $ganalytics;?></textarea>
```

Comment: can you please set you complete code from php and html file